# How to select one column with all distinct values based on some clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I essentially like to have one query which I'll execute one time and like to have the result (no multiple query execution) and definitely, the query should use simple MySQL structure (no complex/advanced structure to be used like BEGIN, loop, cursor).

Say I've two tables.

```
1st Table =     Country (id(PK), name);
2nd Table =     Businessman (id(PK), name, city, country_id(FK))
```

Like to SELECT all countries, whose businessmen are from distinct cities. No two businessmen exist in one country, who are from the same city. If so, that country will not be selected by the SELECT clause.

Country

```
id  name
1   India
2   China
3   Bahrain
4   Finland
5   Germany
6   France
```

Businessman

```
id  name    city        country_id
1   BM1     Kolkata     1
2   BM2     Delhi       1
3   BM3     Mumbai      1
4   BM4     Beijing     2
5   BM5     Paris       6
6   BM6     Beijing     2
7   BM7     Forssa      4
8   BM8     Anqing      2
9   BM9     Berlin      5
10  BM10    Riffa       3
11  BM11    Nice        6
12  BM12    Helsinki    4
13  BM13    Bremen      5
14  BM14    Wiesbaden   5
15  BM15    Angers      6
16  BM16    Sitra       3
17  BM17    Adliya      3
18  BM18    Caen        6
19  BM19    Jinjiang    2
20  BM20    Tubli       3   
21  BM21    Duisburg    5
22  BM22    Helsinki    4
23  BM23    Kaarina     4
24  BM24    Bonn        5
25  BM25    Kemi        4
```

In this respect, China and Finland shouldn't be listed.
I've attempted using count and group by, but no luck.

Can you please help me to build up this query.

Comment: Add some sample table data (incl "duplicates"), and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt!

Comment: Do you think the way you pasted your table data is anywhere easy to read or understand?

Comment: Please add what you tried

Comment: Using `count` and `group by` sounds good :-) Show us your query and we'll tell you what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is, all you need is to join Businessman table and count cities and distinct cities and if they equal that means all businessmen are from different cities:

```
SELECT 
    c.`id`,
    c.`name`,
    COUNT(b.`id`) AS BusinessmanCount,
    COUNT(b.`city`) AS CityCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.`city`) AS DistinctCityCount
FROM `countries` c
INNER JOIN Businessman b ON c.`id` = b.`country_id`
GROUP BY c.`id`
HAVING CityCount = DistinctCityCount
```

For minified version what you exactly need:

```
SELECT 
    c.`id`,
    c.`name`
FROM `countries` c
INNER JOIN Businessman b ON c.`id` = b.`country_id`
GROUP BY c.`id`
HAVING COUNT(b.`city`) = COUNT(DISTINCT b.`city`)
```

Comment: Thats the right answer. I've made a test of it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60226c/2). Also, if you need only countries you can just use `HAVING COUNT(b.city) = COUNT(DISTINCT b.city)` in having clause.

Comment: @SergeyLobanov thanks for the comment, sure I've already updated my answer before, including what you suggest

Comment: Hello George, Thanks a lot for the solution and it resolves the issue. My logic was exactly same but as I mentioned earlier in some comment, I didn't know how to compare two counts using having clause, I gave up. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You need either nested aggregations:

```
select *
from Country
where id in
 (
   select country_id
   from
    (
      select city, country_id, 
         count(*) as cnt -- get the number of rows per country/city
      from Businessman
      group by city, country_id
    ) as dt
   group by country_id
   having max(cnt) = 1 -- return only those countries where all counts are unique
  )
```

Or compare two counts:

```
select *
from Country
where id in
 (
   select country_id
   from Businessman
   group by country_id
   having count(*) = count(distinct city) -- number of cities is equal to umber of rows
 )
```

Comment: I fixed `country_id` to `id` in where clauses in your selects. Also this queries works too, but to me, George's query looks cleaner and probably will work faster, but It depends on the circumstances.

Comment: @SergeyLobanov: Yep, my query #1 is a bit overcomplicated (but could be modified to *not more than n per city*). For query#2 performance probably depends on the number of rows in Businessman, it's mainly *join before aggregate* vs. *aggregate before join*. I like ThorstenKettner's approach of *not those countries with more than one*

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think we should have waited for you to show your own query, because one learns best from mistakes and their explanations. However, now that you've got answers already:

Yes, you need `group by` and `count`. I'd group by cities to see if I got duplicates. Then select countries and exclude those that have duplicate cities.

```
select *
from country
where id not in 
(
  select country_id
  from businessmen
  group by city, country_id
  having count(*) > 1
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Thorsten; yes you said it; now let me explain, I did the same thing as above but didn't know how to compare two counts.. The logic was same.